# Accessing android phone sdcard through pc browser

Tags: android, ip-address, remote-access, file-sharing

I am a newbie to android. I need to develop an application in which I can access my android phone sd card from my pc's browser by just using the ip address generated from my phone. 
I got Ip address but couldnt find any example for this. Please if any one has any example or any knowledge please reply. I am in urgent need of it. 
Thank you in advance.

KNOWLEDGE GROWS BY SHARING....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its no simple thing.  You need to implement something like an [FTP server](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/) on your phone.  Or a [samba server](http://www.samba.org/cifs/docs/what-is-smb.html).

Failing that you can download one of the [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andsmb&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImx5c2Vzb2Z0LmFuZHNtYiJd) that already provide you with a samba server.

***Edit***: You'd probably do well looking at something like [swiftp](http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/).

Comment: How to create FTP server on phone? Searched for it but couldnt find anything. Please help.

Comment: Thanks but what i have to do is implement my own ftp server just like swiftp. Can i achieve this without using ftp server if both pc and mobile are in same network i mean connected to same wifi network?

Comment: @user1508383: The source code for swiftp is available.  It would be a good starting place.

Comment: ITs just apk file where do i find source of swiftp?

Answer (score 0):

Application of your really interesting. You can download application wifiFileExplorer then translate reverse to get source reference.
Link: http://www.mediafire.com/?7tyvrvh26ekwwxe

Comment: How to reverse the reference from the apk? How do i get the source code from apk. I am using ubuntu and couldnt find any proper answer. Please help.

Comment: you read the link : http://a4apphack.com/security/sec-code/extract-android-apk-from-market-and-decompile-it-to-java-source

Answer (score 0):

You can download application wifiFileExplorer then translate reverse to get source reference
it's not possible